# select from LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called DICT that have a foreign key on table applicant and other table called DT.

The table DT has a foreign key into table applicant.

What I want to do is to select:

- DICT.*
- the applicant related to the DICT
- the  DT related to the DICT and the applicant related to this DT

I have this incomplete code

```
SELECT DICT.*,DT.*,applicant.*
FROM DICT
LEFT OUTER JOIN DICT.dt = DT.id_DT 
INNER JOIN applicant  ON DICT.applicant =applicant .id_applicant 
WHERE DICT.id_DICT = 5
```

I have to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on DT because some time DICT don't have DT
and this code give DICT, their linked applicant record and DT but it don't give the applicant related to the DT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I gather OP correctly, the problem is that you need to join the `applicant` table *twice* in order for it to show up twice in the list of columns. One set is the applicant record joined to the DT record, and one set is the applicant record joined to the DICT record.

```
SELECT DICT.*,dict_applicant.*,dt_applicant.*,DT.*
FROM DICT
INNER JOIN applicant AS dict_applicant ON DICT.applicant = dict_applicant.id_applicant 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DT on DICT.dt = DT.id_DT 
INNER JOIN applicant AS dt_applicant on DT.applicant = dt_applicant.id_applicant
WHERE DICT.id_DICT = 5
```